Receiving 403 Forbidden Error in PHP on Ubuntu 22.04
I am encountering a persistent issue where I receive a 403 Forbidden error whenever I attempt to access any PHP file within directories on my Apache web server, except for index.php. This problem appeared suddenly without any recent major changes to the configuration.
Here are the details of the problem:

Error Details: When accessing PHP files like login_process.php within directories, I receive the 403 Forbidden error.
File Permissions: I have verified that file permissions are correctly set for the directories and files in question.
Apache Error Log: The Apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) consistently shows entries like the following for files within my working directory:
[Time] [access_compat:error] [pid 841806] [client IP] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example.com/dir/anyfile-except-index.php, referer: https://example.com/dir/
Apache Configuration (apache2.conf): My Apache configuration allows AllowOverride All and Require all granted within the <Directory /var/www/> block.

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking Apache configurations, file permissions, and .htaccess files, but I have not been able to resolve this issue.
Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to debug and fix this 403 Forbidden error for PHP files within directories on my Apache web server?
Update: By setting AllowOverride None in apache2.conf solved my problem. But I wanted the custom .htaccess rules also in the directory to apply.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

This error was raised by mine earlier time fault only. In the web root of our domain. This .htaccess code is there:
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

So, after fixing the code, my project works properly.
Thanks all of you for my help in my own fault by giving your precious time.
